# Search class in a element

Tags: jquery

I try something like this

```
   <td><i class='fas fa-exchange-alt pointer disabled asignar'></i><td>
    
   $(td).find("i").find(".asignar").click((e: any){
        alert("Hello");
   })
```

But doesn´t work, alert not show. I suppose that jquery selector is wrong.

What is the correct way to select this element based on the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `<i>` has already that class, no need to query children of `<i>` using `.find()`
- If `td` is not an in-memory cached element, use it as selector: `$("td")`

```js
$("td").find("i.asignar").click((evt) => {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<td>
    <i class='fas fa-exchange-alt pointer disabled asignar'></i>
<td>      

$('td').find("i.asignar").click((e: any){ 
    alert("Hello"); 
})
```

As you are targeting the `i` element which have class `.asignar` you should pass both tag and class selector in the same `find`.

If you call `$('td').find('i').find('.asignar')` It means you are look for all element which has class `asignar` which is children of `i` tag and has parent `td` tag